# Change Modal Card Color Flowbite-Svelte

Tags: sveltekit, flowbite

I am trying to change the card color of a modal made with Flowbite-Svelte but I cannot find a way to get to it. Right now it is a blueish gray and I would like to change it.
Changing the `bg` tailwind property only changes the backdrop but not the actual modal.

Does anyone have experience with Flowbite-Svelte?

https://flowbite-svelte.com/

[image: Modal]

**Code:**

```
<Button btnClass="tracking-[.35em] font-semibold drop-shadow-md text-xs bg-black py-4 px-8 text-white uppercase font-display rounded dark:text-black dark:bg-white" on:click={() => defaultModal = true}>
 Default modal
 </Button>

 <Modal backdropClasses="bg-none backdrop-blur-md" class="font-display" title="Terms of Service" bind:open={defaultModal}>
 <p class="text-base font-sans font-extralight leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
 With less than a month to go before the European Union enacts new consumer privacy laws for its citizens, 
 companies around the world are updating their terms of service agreements to comply.
</p>
<p class="text-base font-sans font-extralight leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
The European Union’s General Data Protection Regulation (G.D.P.R.) goes into effect on May 25 and is meant to ensure a common set of data rights in the European Union. It requires organizations to notify users as soon as possible of high-risk data breaches that could personally affect them.
</p>
<svelte:fragment slot='footer'>
<Button btnClass="tracking-[.35em] font-semibold drop-shadow-md text-xs bg-black py-4 px-8 text-white uppercase font-display rounded dark:text-black dark:bg-white" on:click={() => alert('Handle "success"')}>Accept</Button>
<Button btnClass="tracking-[.35em] drop-shadow-md font-semibold text-black text-xs bg-white py-4 px-8 uppercase font-display rounded dark:bg-black dark:text-white dark:border" color="alternative">Decline</Button>
</svelte:fragment>
</Modal>
```

`

Comment: Looks like this currently doesn't have this feature. I tried adding `backdropClasses="dark"` and `backdropClasses="light"` and changes the modal's bg, the library doesn't send props to that frame.